# 日本語で深層学習の用語

Tags: 深層学習, 日本語, 英語

皆さん、おはようございます。

今履歴書は英語から日本語で翻訳しますのに、日本語はまだ上手じゃないですのが、知らない用語が沢山ありますけど、Wikipediaは助けてない所は多いですので、スタック・オーバーフローに聞いています。

#### 知らない用語は英語で：

- Viewpoint invariance
- Combining multiple neural networks to improve generalization
- Restricted Boltzmann machines (RBMs)
- Stacking RBMs to make Deep Belief Nets
- generative pre-training
- Modeling hierarchical structure with neural nets
- Image style transfer
- Sequence-to-sequence
- Bilingual word embedding
- Bilingual text alignment
- One-shot learning
- Differentiable neural computers
- Capsule Neural Networks

ありがとうございます！
良い一日を！

テオドア

Answer (score 5):

リスト中の用語は新しいものが多いです。定まった訳が無いものもあります。英語のまま書くことができるなら、そうするのが良いでしょう。

また、日本語には複数形が無いことにも注意してください。たとえば、"neural network**s**" に対応するカタカナは「ニューラルネットワーク**ス**」ではなく「ニューラルネットワーク」であることが多いです。

Since some of the listed terms are new, there are terms which have no well-known translation. If you can leave them in English, I think it's better.

Also, note that Japanese language doesn't have the plural form of nouns. So, for example, Katakana for "neural network**s**" is "ニューラルネットワーク", not "ニューラルネットワーク**ス**", in many cases.

- Viewpoint invariance

  - 「視点不変性」
  - viewpoint: 「視点」
  - invariance: 「不変性」
- Combining multiple neural networks to improve generalization

  - 「複数のニューラルネットワークを組み合わせて汎化能力を上げる」
  - generalization ability: 「汎化能力」
  - neural network: 「ニューラルネットワーク」 or 「ニューラルネット」 (abbreviation)
- Restricted Boltzmann machines (RBMs)

  - 「Restricted Boltzmann machine (RBM)」 or 「制限付きボルツマンマシン (RBM)」 or 「制限ボルツマンマシン (RBM)」
  - Boltzmann machine: 「ボルツマンマシン」 or 「ボルツマン機械」
- Stacking RBMs to make Deep Belief Nets

  - 「RBM を重ねて Deep Belief Net を作る」
  - Deep Belief Net: 「Deep Belief Net」 or 「ディープ・ビリーフ・ネット」
- generative pre-training

  - 「generative pre-training」 or 「生成的事前訓練」
  - pre-training: 「事前訓練」
- Modeling hierarchical structure with neural nets

  - 「ニューラルネットで階層的構造をモデリングする」 or 「ニューラルネットを使って階層構造をモデル化する」
- Image style transfer

  - 「画風変換」 or 「画風変換機」
  - image style: 「画風」 or 「画像の作風」
  - transfer (as noun): 「変換機」
- Sequence-to-sequence

  - 「sequence-to-sequence」 or 「列から列への」?
  - I think the meaning of this adjective can change according to a context.
- Bilingual word embedding

  - 「bilingual word embedding」 or 「バイリンガル単語埋め込み」??? I don't know the exact translation.
  - word embedding: 「単語埋め込み」 or simply, 「word embedding」

    - or, 「語の分散表現」 as the translation of "distributed representations for words"
- Bilingual text alignment

  - 「bilingual text alignment」 or 「バイリンガル・テキスト・アラインメント」 or 「2つの言語間のテキストアラインメント」??? I don't know the exact translation...
  - text alignment: 「テキストアラインメント」
- One-shot learning

  - 「one-shot learning」 or 「one-shot 学習」 or 「ワンショット学習」
  - I prefer the first one.
- Differentiable neural computers

  - 「Differentiable Neural Computer」 or 「ディファレンシャブル・ニューラル・コンピュータ」
  - I prefer the first one. I don't know the well-known translation of this term.
  - differentiable: 「微分可能」 or 「可微分」
- Capsule Neural Networks

  - 「Capsule Neural Network」 or 「カプセルニューラルネットワーク」

#### 補足 (Notes)

日本語の文法についての質問があれば、[Japanese Language Stack Exchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) というサイトもあります。

If you have questions about Japanese grammar, there is also a site called [Japanese Language Stack Exchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/).

---

<sub>訳語を考えるのに、友人からの意見を参考にしました。この場を借りて感謝いたします。ありがとう。</sub>

Comment: 本当にありがとうありがとうございました！助かれました！

Comment: Thank You very much for the descriptive explanations for each of my requests! I could not find any information online about those terms and I appreciate Your help very much, You saved me a lot of efforts!

Have an awesome day!